# Can relate to only one element

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am using Neo4j OGM 2.0.4 driver with Java. I have trouble with adding more than one relationship to element.

I do something like this:

```
Site site1 = new Site();
site1.setTitle("Site 1");
site1.setHtmlCode("Content of site 1");
Site site2 = new Site();

Site subsite1  = new Site();
subsite1.setTitle("Subsite 1");
subsite1.setHtmlCode("Content of subsite 1");
subsite1.setParent(site1);

Site subsite2  = new Site();
subsite2.setTitle("Subsite 2");
subsite2.setHtmlCode("Content of subsite 2");
subsite2.setParent(site1);

session.deleteAll(Site.class);

session.save(site1);

session.save(subsite1);
session.save(subsite2);
```

When I want to show all Site nodes (on localhost:7474) then "Subsite 1" has no relationship.

```
@NodeEntity
public class Site extends Entity
{
  private String _title;
  private String _htmlCode;

  @Relationship(type = "SITE_CREATED_BY")
  Author _author;

  @Relationship(type = "IS_CHILD")
  Set<Site> _parentSite;

  @Relationship(type = "IS_CHILD", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
  Set<Site> _childSites;

  public Site()
  {
    _parentSite = new HashSet();
    _childSites = new HashSet();
  }

  public void setTitle(String title)
  {
    _title = title;
  }

  public String getTitle()
  {
    return _title;
  }

  public void setHtmlCode(String htmlCode)
  {
    _htmlCode = htmlCode;
  }

  public String getHtmlCode()
  {
    return _htmlCode;
  }

  public void setAuthor(Author author)
  {
    _author = author;
  }

  public void setParent(Site site)
  {
    _parentSite.add(site);
  }
}
```

Entity:
    public abstract class Entity
    {
      private Long id;
      private final ZonedDateTime _dateOfCreation;

```
  Entity()
  {
    _dateOfCreation = ZonedDateTime.now();
  }

  public Long getId()
  {
    return id;
  }

  public ZonedDateTime getDateOfCreation()
  {
    return _dateOfCreation;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o)
  {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || id == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Entity entity = (Entity) o;

    return id.equals(entity.id);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode()
  {
    return (id == null) ? -1 : id.hashCode();
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case where you have two relationships in different directions between the same type of node, first, make sure that you annotate both the fields as well as setter/accessor methods with the @Relationship,specifying the direction.

`Site` in your object model has references to both the parent and children, but when you create sites, they do not seem consistent with the model. `Subsite1` and `Subsite2` both set their parents to `site1` but `site` has no record of its children (should be both subsites). Should work if your object and graph models are consistent.